# Latex cannot add author

Tags: latex

I am using overleaf to edit my article. Here is my content:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
% if you need to pass options to natbib, use, e.g.:
%     \PassOptionsToPackage{numbers, compress}{natbib}
% before loading neurips_2019   

% ready for submission
% \usepackage{neurips_2019} 

% to compile a preprint version, e.g., for submission to arXiv, add add the
% [preprint] option:
%     \usepackage[preprint]{neurips_2019}   

% to compile a camera-ready version, add the [final] option, e.g.:
\usepackage[]{neurips_2019} 

% to avoid loading the natbib package, add option nonatbib:
%     \usepackage[nonatbib]{neurips_2019}   

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % use 8-bit T1 fonts
\usepackage{hyperref}       % hyperlinks
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage{booktabs}       % professional-quality tables
\usepackage{amsfonts}       % blackboard math symbols
\usepackage{nicefrac}       % compact symbols for 1/2, etc.
\usepackage{microtype}      % microtypography
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\title{On the General Molecular Theory of Heat}
\author{A. Einstein}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Here is what it looks like: 
[image]

As you can see, I have already set the author to be A. Einstein, but it still shows the default anonymous author. I wonder why would that happen and how should I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like the `neurips_2019` package messes with the author settings. Without using that package, the author appears as expected.

Looking into that neurips_2019.sty style file, it has a concept of "an anonymized submission". If that is set, it redefines `@maketitle` to use the hard-coded values you see. You can turn that off by marking your document as final:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[final]{neurips_2019} % <-- note "final" here
\title{On the General Molecular Theory of Heat}
\author{A. Einstein}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The `final` option will put the conference location at the bottom of the first page. You can replace `final` with `preprint`, which will then put "Preprint. Under review." at the bottom of the first page.

I don't understand the motivation for this behavior, so it's probably best to check with the package maintainers / conference organizers on what you should use.